# Audio Stream using Python/Tornado to act a "radio"

Tags: python, streaming, tornado, gstreamer

I'm creating a little project in Python that uses Tornado to host a RESTful API for retrieving, searching and adding audio files. So far I can output an audio file via

```
self.set_header('Content-type', mimeType)
self.write(open(fileName).read())
```

However, I'd like to be able to create a "radio" station of sorts. It's really just a glorified playlist, but I'd like for it be synced across multiple computers.
I plan on simply having each station write its upcoming tracks to a file/database and when the input stream from one song finishes it will begin outputting the next one. If one doesn't exist it simply stops the stream. The ability to pause the stream would be a bonus, but at this point in time I'd just like to have a stream up and running.

I've looked around, and all I can find is GStreamer (which has a Python port, but I can't get it to work on Mac) and the odd incomplete/old/abandoned projects. I am aware of the SHOUTcast protocol, but I'm not too sure how to stream the audio in a "radio station" style.

I am new to Python programming (I've mainly worked with PHP), so maybe I'm just not looking in the right places or searching for the right things?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A "radio station" typically means that the _server_ handles a playlist, and streams one song at a time; any client who connects up joins in the middle of the current song. If that's what you want, GStreamer, icecast/SHOUTcast, etc. are perfect for you (although you may want to consider HTML5 AV streaming instead). But if you want to send a playlist that each client starts at the beginning, just send a playlist (e.g., a file full of URLs to MP3s) and parse it on the client side.

Comment: I do plan on offering playlists to be downloaded/modified etc., but I'll take a look at the streaming options you mentioned (although as mentioned, I can't get GStreamer to work), thank you!

Comment: But do you want each new client to start at the top of the playlist, or at the current track? For the latter, you want radio-style streaming; for the former, you don't; just give the client URLs to download and play. (If you're worried about hiding the download URLs to prevent piracy… well, that isn't actually possible, but there are a number of half-assed solutions in current use that the RIAA have implicitly decided are good enough, so you might want to use one of them instead of inventing something new, even if it's better…)

Comment: Each client should start at the current timestamp in the current track, like a radio.  
Luckily piracy will not be an issue since this is intended to be for internal use only, but I am interested in looking at ways of helping prevent piracy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I (think I) understand what you want, I think the simplest way to get started is something like this:

First, set up a stock icecast server. For now, just run it as a manually-configured standalone daemon.

Next, set up a stock ices or similar source client that just streams playlists that you give it through the server. Again, for now, configure and run it manually.

Next, write a Tornado server that serves up whatever UI, metadata, and/or stream addresses you want to clients.

You can write a custom client, or you can just serve up "radio playlist" .m3u files that will open in the user's default player. (This is just a file with the URL to the icecast stream address in it. Playing this .m3u in most media players will stream from the given URL, which is just serving up an infinitely-long MP3 file over HTTP.)

Most of what you might want to add on top of this, you'll be interacting with the source client. For example, you want to keep a database of tracks and generate the playlists dynamically. You may want end users to be able to add to or edit the database. And so on. Depending on how fancy you want to get, you may just want to drive ices by modifying its input files and running it as a child process (`subprocess.Popen`) so you can easily start and stop instances, or you may want to write a custom source client from scratch around shout-python.

If you also need to control the server, you can similarly drive it by editing its config files and running it as a child process.

Comment: I'd like to control the icecast server through a RESTful API using the Tornado server, so I'll try and setup a server using `shout-python`.  
I'm currently getting `shout.ShoutException: Couldn't connect` using the example, but I've installed libshout and shout-python, so I'll have to debug that for a while :)  
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing up two pieces. The server (`icecast`) just repeats a source client's stream to listener clients. The source client (`ices`, or the thing you build with `shout-python`) connects to the server and feeds it the stream. You need both. If you want to change the playlist, insert a message, pause the stream, etc., that's all done by the source client.

Comment: Yes, I was getting the 2 confused. I'll take a look at setting up an icecast server and have a mess around with `ices` first, and then try and build my system using `shout-python`. Thanks for all the help!